# Is it possible to calculate a minimum initial speed required to travel a distance x, in time t with an acceleration a

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to work out the minimum initial speed required for a ball to travel a distance x in a time of t, given that a there is a constant acceleration of -friction?

I know that given a distance $x$, and an initial velocity $u$, and an acceleration of -friction I can work out the time taken t to travel the distance $x$.

$v^2 = u^2 + 2ax$

and $t = (v - u) / a$

Is it possible to work out a minimum initial speed given the information for $x$, $t$ and $a$??

Answer (score 1):

You have $x=ut+\frac 12at^2$, so given $a,x$ and $t$ you can solve the quadratic for $u$